# Windows Forms: DataGridView Problem with backgroundcolor after sorting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a **Windows Forms datagridview**, where the rows have different **background-colors**.

The problem is, that the background-colors disappear after **sorting** (click on a row header) and all rows are again white (default color). What could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: is the Sorted event being handled?

Comment: which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/120007/datagridview-sort-looses-cell-backcolor) submitted to Microsoft on June 2005 this is by design for Visual Studio 2005:

> Thank you for your bug report. The
>   behavior you notice is by design.
>   Sorting a databound grid causes all
>   rows to be recreated (called a
>   ListChangedType.Reset). This causes
>   your formatting to be lost. You need
>   to use the DataBindingComplete event
>   to apply styles and check for the
>   ListChangedType.Reset to know when to
>   apply your styling. Alternatively you
>   can use the CellFormatting event.
>   Ideally all your formatting can be
>   done inside the CellFormatting since
>   it is applied dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

Use Sorted event and you can restore backcolor of your datagridview.

```
private void datagridview_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you can restore backcolor of datagridview in this function.
   //example given below
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in datagridview.Rows)
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 0, 0);            
}
```

Comment: I'm going with this, but retaining the edited colours before sort, then re-applying in this sorted event. A bit of extra work that we shouldn't really have to do, but there we go.