# How Retain Programmatically-Colored Backgrounds of DataGridView on Sorting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

In a VB.NET WinForms project I'm creating in VS2013 I have this code to detect when a DataGridView's cell contents is changed:

```
Private Sub dgvEmployees_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.CellValueChanged
    ' Pass the row and cell indexes to the method so we can change the color of the edited row
    CompareDgvToDataSource("employees", e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource(ByVal dataSetName As String, ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer)
    ' Takes a dataset and the row and column indexes, checks if the row is different from the DataSet and colors the row appropriately

    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanges As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

    If Not dsChanges Is Nothing Then
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In dsChanges.Tables("employees").Rows
            If DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID.ToString = dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("employeeID").Value.ToString Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dsChanges.Tables("employees").Columns.Count - 1

                    If dtrow.RowState.ToString = DataRowState.Added.ToString Then
                        ' TODO: Color entire new row
                    ElseIf dsChanges.Tables(dataSetName).Rows(0).HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original) Then
                        If Not dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(dtrow(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                            Console.WriteLine("Employees ID: " & DirectCast(dtrow, EmployeesDataSet.employeesRow).employeeID)
                            dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                        Else
                            ' TODO: Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, if the user sorts the DGV with any cells colored, after the sort, none of the cells are colored.

What do I need to do to retain cell background color for the correct cell(s) after a sort?

**Final Working Code**

```
Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource()

    ' Force ending Edit mode so the last edited value is committed
    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanged As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added Or DataRowState.Modified)

    If Not dsChanged Is Nothing Then
        Dim dtChanged As DataTable = dsChanged.Tables("employees")

        For Each row As DataRow In dtChanged.Rows
            For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvEmployees.Rows
                If dgvRow.Cells("employeeID").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    If dgvRow.Cells("employeeID").Value.Equals(row.Item("employeeID")) Then
                        ' Found the row in the DGV that matches the current Changed Row
                        For i As Integer = 0 To dtChanged.Columns.Count - 1

                            If Not row(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(row(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                                ' Found a Cell in the current DGV row that is different from the DataSet
                                Console.WriteLine("Row index: " & dtChanged.Rows.IndexOf(row))
                                dgvEmployees.Rows(dgvRow.Index).Cells(i + 1).Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                            Else
                                ' Need to change the BackColor back to what it should be based on its original alternating row color
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If

            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but can't you just handle the "Sorted" event and add your programmatic coloring there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I +1'd your question 'cause it's a fun challenge :-)

I wasn't aware that the coloring of a row or cell would be lost after a sort.  Curious.  Here's what I would do.  Create a ViewState variable (or some other object/variable that will persist) that is an array of integers.  As  you color a row, ad the ID of that row to your variable.

Then, on the DataGridView.OnSorted event, run through that array and re-color each row.

Info on the DataGridView.OnSorted event here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx

Lemme know if this makes sense, or if you need any more help.

**EDIT:**

There may be a better solution:

[Windows Forms: DataGridView Problem with backgroundcolor after sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278576/windows-forms-datagridview-problem-with-backgroundcolor-after-sorting)

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

This guy found a creative solution by using an unbound DataGridView.  By design, a bound DGV will re-bind when you sort, and all style changes are lost.  But if you use an unbound DGV, then all the styles remain after a sort.

Scroll to the very bottom to see how he solved it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/f7bde482-cc02-48be-b917-9fdfab73bc18/datagridview-rows-cells-state-not-retaining-after-sorting

More on Creating an Unbound Windows Forms DataGridView Control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3ce6k8(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Great stuff, Casey! I'm surprised I didn't run into those examples that you found when I was searching. I'll go through this stuff and post my results here.

Comment: I settled on a suggestion in the answer to the question from your first link. I used the DataBindingComplete event to call my method of iterating through the DataSet. I'll post my final, working code. Thanks!